# navigating from class Activity extends android.app.Activity to normal component

Tags: nativescript

I have used @javaproxy for one of the component and created a class that extend android.app.Activity. Now I want to navigate to other component. Could not get router instance.And tried to do with android Intent but could not get class instance for parameter. Can any suggest me a way to navigate out of this class (edited)

@JavaProxy('com.tns.NativeScriptActivity')
class Activity extends android.app.Activity {

Comment: May I know why you have decided to extend the activity in first place, also may I know which version of {N} you are using?

Comment: @Manoj I am using bitly plugin in my application so I need onNewIntent(intent: android.content.Intent): void . for this method i have taken this approach 
"tns-android": { "version": "5.1.0" } –

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you are using {N} 5.x, you must be extending `android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity` as given in the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/android-runtime/advanced-topics/extend-application-activity).

The ideal way to access Angular components easily would be, triggering an event on application module and listen to the same from any of your Angular component where you can of course inject all the dependencies like RouterExtensions.

May be something like this in your onNewIntent callback,

```
application.android.notify({
    eventName: "newintent",
    object: application.android,
    data: intent
});
```

In your Angular component listen to the event like,

```
application.android.on("newintent", (args) => {
    const intent = args.data;
});
```

Comment: but onNewIntent is a life cycle method of activity. how can we call notify on that